# css issue while downloading png image from svg in nvd3

Tags: css, canvas, svg

I have one line chart using nvd3.js . I want to download this chart in .png format.
I am using canvas and sending the canvas.toDataURL("image/png") to server and downloading the image, but the image is not in proper shape .it seems the css(nvd3.css) is not getting applied.

Any help will be really heplfull.

Thanks,
chandan

Comment: Seeing your code would be really helpful.

Comment: In general, you should apply all the styles in your code rather than through CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same requirement and "[example of how to export a png directly from an svg](http://bl.ocks.org/deanmalmgren/22d76b9c1f487ad1dde6)" solved my problem (internally it adopted [svg-crowbar](http://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/) code. basically, you need to "explicitly set css style" for all svg element.